# CSS alternate row order for display:table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML page with a list of items and their descriptions. The styling is done exclusively in CSS, in the pursuit of keeping information separate from layout.

Is it possible to use only CSS so that for every other row, the columns are reversed? I'd like to avoid using an HTML `table`, or manually reversing the columns in HTML, and I'd like to keep using `<ul>` and `<li>`, since it matches the kind of data that is displayed.

**What I have:**

[image: Current layout]

```css
img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
}
.item-name, .item-details {
    display: table-row;
}
.item-pic, .item-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
}
.item-name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="green.gif"></span>
            <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Green</span>
                <span class="item-details">This is a green item</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="red.gif"></span>
            <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Red</span>
                <span class="item-details">This is a red item</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="blue.gif"></span>
            <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Blue</span>
                <span class="item-details">This is a blue item</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="yellow.gif"></span>
            <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Yellow</span>
                <span class="item-details">This is a yellow item</span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I would like:**

[image]

Comment: As far as targeting goes, you could target alternative rows with nth-child https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child then you could use flex to reverse the order of the items or even use float I believe

Comment: why use `display: table;` in the first place and not the correct tool's such as `Flexbox`  and `CSS-Grid` which also allow the use of the `order`-property or `grid-area`- declaration.

Comment: I tried to use `flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse`, but I couldn't figure out how to combine it with `display: table`. I hadn't considered dropping `display: table` altogether, because in my head the layout is a classic table - but I'm not married to the idea. The requirement for the text side to contain multiple rows remains though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS code. It uses `display:flex` on the `li` tags, with `reverse` order on every second one (`:nth-child(even)`) , and `display: block` on the two text spans to make them go across the whole width of their parent and therefore place them below each other. Other details see below:

(The width of the container can be adjusted as desired, it could as well be 100% to span the whole width of its parent)

```css
img {
  max-width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

ul>li:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.item-text > * {
  display: block;
}
.item-pic,
.item-text {
  padding: 10px;
}
.item-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="item-pic"><img src="green.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
         <span class="item-name">Green</span>
         <span class="item-details">This is a green item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="red.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Red</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a red item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="blue.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Blue</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a blue item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="yellow.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Yellow</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a yellow item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: up-voted this answer instead of the previos one because it contains the better explaination of the solution. Also using `reverse` property on flexbox is a more simple solution then to reorder imho.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to apply this successfully to the actual project. Might I suggest using `align-items: flex-start` instead of `center`, as it's more consistent with the original `vertical-align: top`?

Comment: @SirAthos `flex-start` at the crossing of the main axis and side axis. By default (`flex-direction: row`) it is the top-left corner. With `flex-direction: column-reverse` it would be the bottom left corner as example.

Comment: @SirAthos Oh yes, I forgot about that when erasing the old rules. I just used it in my example since with that little content it looks better IMO, but of course you are right. (I changed it now)

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for the useful clarification! So `row-reverse` plus `flex-start` should align to the top-right then?

Comment: @SirAthos correct as long as we talk about `LTR` in `RTL` the opposite of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a combination of nth-child and flex. With nth-child, you can easily target alternating rows with `odd` or `even` keywords. Then it just a matter of setting the `li` to flex and changing the order for even row. (EDIT: updated this to use row reverse instead as it is indeed easier)

I removed all the able related styles

```css
img {
  max-width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


.item-pic,
.item-text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block; // no need for this if you use a div
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li:nth-child( even ) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="green.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Green</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a green item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="red.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Red</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a red item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="blue.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Blue</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a blue item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="item-pic"><img src="yellow.gif"></span>
      <span class="item-text">
                <span class="item-name">Yellow</span>
      <span class="item-details">This is a yellow item</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found the usage of `order` actually interesting to illustrate that you could change the columns in any order if you had more than two, not just reverse them. Ultimately, I chose the other answer as the solution because it explained in more detail and it tried to preserve the formatting used in the question (thus making it a little easier to apply to the project).

Comment: thanks for the heads up